# React websocket get stuck on 'CONNECTING' readyState on component unmount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, websocket, react-context

I have created a context for handling websocket connection in my application. Here is the implementation:

```
import { useAppSelector } from '../../app/hooks';
import {
    selectCurrentSelectedCommunityTopic,
    selectCurrentSelectedCommunityTopicParticipantsState,
    selectCurrentSelectedUserCommunity,
    selectCurrentSelectedUserCommunityMembersState,
} from '../../app/appSlice';
import { shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';
import { createContext, ReactNode, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { getTenantId, getUserId } from '../../services/UserService';
import { TimelineEvent } from '../../models/post/posts';
import { useHandleTimelineSocketMessage } from '../../hooks/useHandleTimelineSocketMessage';

export type WebSocketSendMethod =
    | ((data: string | ArrayBufferLike | Blob | ArrayBufferView) => void)
    | undefined;
export type TimelineWebSocketContextProps = [
    WebsocketReadyState,
    WebSocketSendMethod
];
export enum WebsocketReadyState {
    UNINSTANTIATED = -1,
    CONNECTING = 0,
    OPEN = 1,
    CLOSING = 2,
    CLOSED = 3,
}
export const TimelineWebSocketContext =
    createContext<TimelineWebSocketContextProps>([-1, undefined]);
export type TimelineWebSocketProviderProps = {
    children: ReactNode;
};
export const TimelineWebSocketProvider = ({
    children,
}: TimelineWebSocketProviderProps) => {
    const selectedCommunity = useAppSelector(
        selectCurrentSelectedUserCommunity,
        shallowEqual
    );
    const selectedTopic = useAppSelector(
        selectCurrentSelectedCommunityTopic,
        shallowEqual
    );
    const { topicParticipants, status: topicParticipantRequestStatus } =
        useAppSelector(
            selectCurrentSelectedCommunityTopicParticipantsState,
            shallowEqual
        );
    const { communityMembers, status: communityMemberRequestStatus } =
        useAppSelector(
            selectCurrentSelectedUserCommunityMembersState,
            shallowEqual
        );
    const socketRef = useRef<WebSocket | null>(null);
    const didUnmount = useRef(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log('timeline unmount');
            didUnmount.current = true;
        };
    }, []);
    const handleSocketClose = (event: CloseEvent) => {
        console.log('closing socket', event, 'unmount=>', didUnmount);
        if (event.wasClean) {
            console.log(
                `[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`
            );
        } else {
            console.log(
                `[close] Connection died, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`
            );
            initSocket();
        }
    };
    const handleTimelineSocketMessage = useHandleTimelineSocketMessage();
    const handleSocketMessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
        console.log(selectedCommunity, selectedTopic, 'on message');
        if (event.data && selectedTopic && selectedCommunity) {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            handleTimelineSocketMessage(data as TimelineEvent);
        }
    };
    const initSocket = () => {
        let socket: WebSocket;
        if (selectedCommunity) {
            let endpoint = `/${getTenantId()}/${
                selectedCommunity.communityId
            }/${getUserId()}`;

            const url = import.meta.env.VITE_SOCKET_BASE_URL + endpoint;
            socket = new WebSocket(url);
            socket.onmessage = handleSocketMessage;
            socket.onclose = handleSocketClose;
            socketRef.current = socket;
        }
    };
    const cleanupSocket = () => {
        if (socketRef.current) {
            console.log('calling close socket');
            socketRef.current.onclose = null;
            socketRef.current.close();
            socketRef.current = null;
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedCommunity) {
            console.log('calling init socket');
            initSocket();
        }

        return () => {
            cleanupSocket();
        };
    }, [selectedCommunity]);
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            cleanupSocket();
        };
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(
            'socketRef.current?.readyState',
            socketRef.current?.readyState
        );
    }, [socketRef.current]);
    console.log(socketRef.current, 'socket instance');
    return (
        <TimelineWebSocketContext.Provider
            value={[
                socketRef.current ? socketRef.current?.readyState : -1,
                socketRef.current?.send.bind(socketRef.current),
            ]}
        >
            {children}
        </TimelineWebSocketContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

I am using this context in a react router route's component. Everything works fine when I visit the route that uses this context. But when I go to other route and come back to this route, the `readyStatus` keep stuck on `0(Connecting)` state.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?
FYI, the socket server is a reactive spring-boot applciation.